# Why do we need to use Android studio for building a flutter app?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code

What the advantages in using Android studio for building a flutter app?
How does it differ from visual studio code?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the app in both IDEs. Android Studio is more focus on mobile development so maybe there are some functions that make the work easier, but in general lines, both are completely valid. If you have worked before with Vscode, for example, you can feel more comfortable with something that you know how it works. But both of them works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have other Ide, but Android studio is the one officially supported by google, creator of flutter. Other famous Ide's include Visual Studio Code, Screenshots, Intelij Idea etc

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of comparisons between these two IDE on the web. You can search easily. I will share two of the relevant sources. [One](https://www.quora.com/Which-IDE-is-good-for-Flutter-development-Android-Studio-or-VS-Code) is:

> Android studio-
>
> Pros
>
> Android Studio is the software built by Google themselves to be used for Android Development. As such, it's certain that support for it will never drop as long as Android apps are still being developed.
>
> Studio is also the tool that Google recommends using for Android development and it's the IDE that gets updates related to Android first.
>
> Cons
>
> Gradle sync fail
> Render problem
> Class can't be found
> Layout
> Reinstall repository
> Update SDK (even with latest version)
>
> Android Studio is the official IDE for Android and it works great as an Android IDE. Unfortunately, that's the only thing it can do. If you want to develop applications for other platforms in Java, you have to learn another IDE as well.
>
> Visual Studio-
>
> Pros
>
> Visual Studio Code comes fairly complete out of the box, but there are many plug-ins available to extend its functionality.
>
> There is very solid TypeScript integration in Visual Studio Code. Both are developed by Microsoft and VSC itself is written in TypeScript.
>
> Visual Studio Code has integrated Git control, guaranteeing speed, data integrity, and support for distributed, non-linear workflows.
>
> These features allow you to have a glance at code without opening it as a whole in a separate tab. Moreover, editing is allowed.
>
> Cons
>
> Sometimes it doesn't tell you if you made a typo in a method name or if a method is not used and several other important features.
>
> Because file search is so slow your results are limited in order to simulate a faster search.
>
> It's absolutely not possible to use this tool with big projects given how long it takes to search for files.
>
> These are the points I looked on comparing AS and VS from my point of view if you have a fast pc then I would suggest you to go with Android STUDIO. Although vs is faster compared to AS but AS have a lote more functionalities which is cherry on cake.

You can read from [the second one](https://blog.codemagic.io/android-studio-vs-visual-studio-code/) too.